# Using change output for custom component in Angular 2+

Tags: angular

I am developing an Angular component `custom-select` that uses a native html select internally.
The template implementation of `custom-select` looks like this:

```
<!-- custom-select.component.html -->

<select class="select" [(ngModel)]="selectedId" (change)="onChange()">
  <option *ngFor="let question of questions" [value]="question.id">{{ question.text }}</option>
</select>
```

So there is a `change` handler for the internal select.

For my custom-select component, I would like to have an output binding named `change`.
So the corresponding TS file for custom-select component looks like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'custom-select',
  templateUrl: './custom-select.component.html'
})
export class CustomSelectComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() options: Array<{ id: string, text: string }>;
  @Output() change = new EventEmitter<string>();

  selectedId = '';

  constructor() { }

  onChange() {
    this.change.emit(this.selectedId);
  }
}
```

Now I can use my custom-select like:

```
<custom-select [options]="options" (change)="onChange($event)"></custom-select>`
```

If I do so, the select change handler is called twice. It seems that the first call is the call I was expecting. The second call seems to be fired by the internal select change handler.

If I rename the handler of custom-select to `selectChange`, everything works just fine.

```
<custom-select [options]="options" (selectChange)="onChange($event)"></custom-select>
```

But since I would like to have a clean API, I prefer naming the output `change` instead of `selectChange`.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Any answer on this? I am facing the same issue now, it triggers the change event twice when the input loses focus.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
@Output('selectChange') change = new EventEmitter<string>();
```

Which refers to the selectChange. You can more about this [here](https://toddmotto.com/component-events-event-emitter-output-angular-2#bonus-custom-property-names)

Comment: That is how I use it currently and that works fine. You are right. But I want to use `@Output('change') change = new EventEmitter<string>();`
so that I can use `change` as attribute when using the component    `<custom-select [options]="options" (change)="onChange($event)"></custom-select>`

Comment: You want to use what?

Comment: They want to override the "change" mechanism with their custom one.

Answer (score 0):

some thing more on this in their official doc: https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#dont-prefix-output-properties